# Unity: How to get the pivot of a game object's sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity I'm trying to get the pivot point of the sprite my game object is using.

I changed the sprite's pivot point for it to be easy while I place the game object(Let's call it A) in the game. Now when I try to spawn another object at the transform of A, the new game object , and I know It's hot It's supposed to do, spawns at the top left ofA. I need to somehow calculate the center of the sprite A is using in world coordinates.

I tried this:

```
Debug.Log(tempGameObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.pivot);
```

But this produces a result as (-80,0,400) while the pivot points are (-0.25, 1.25).

How can I calculate the center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're looking for is the ScreenToWorldPoint method

```
Vector3 center = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(tempGameObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.pivot);
```

Here's the documantation in case you need it
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Comment: This is right. [`Sprite.pivot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-pivot.html) is returned in pixels and needs `ScreenToWorldPoint` to convert it to a normal world pos. Depending on what OP is doing, OP may also have to convert the world pos to the local position of the Sprite with [`InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html).

Comment: @Halil, Remember that if this solved your problem, don't forget to tick it as solved by  accepting it.